# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick?

Tags: html, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток. Почему функция onclick может не работать? Консоль выдает Uncaught ReferenceError: clear_basket is not defined  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```js
function clear_basket(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove_all',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        complete: function() {

        },
        success: function(json) {
            openModalBasket();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="modal-header-remove-btn" onclick="clear_basket();">Очистить</button>
```

Comment: функция в том же файле?

Comment: Нет. Спасибо, скорее всего из-за этого)

Comment: если в другом, то надо скрипт подключить будет